# Samsung S3 Clone "Not registered on network" error

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting

I have a clone S3 which our local Samsung outlet gave to developers in my group. Wireless and all other functions seem to work but when I put in a sim card it does not register and gives the error "Not registerd on network". Searching for the network manually finds the network but can still not register on it.
Azira Patch app says I have no root permissions. Superuser gives and error when I try to install. These are the only solutions I have found so far.
Also the clone S3 have no physical button for menu rather it shows up on the home screen and I cannot get into download mode. Details for the phone are as follows:
Model number: GT-I9300
Android version:4.0.3 
Baseband version: I9300XXLB7
Kernel version:3.0.15-154884-user
Build number:IML74K.I9300XXALB7